# Why can't boost::hana::overload_t be a member of a class

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, boost-hana

So I have a couple of functions, which I get a magic function object, that provides overload resolution on:

```
void foo1();
void foo2(int);


auto foo_ptr = boost::hana::overload(foo1,foo2);
//Later
foo_ptr(12);  //Both Valid (Yeah!)
foo_ptr();
```

But the problem arises when I do something like this:

```
using ptr_t = decltype(foo_ptr);

struct mine
{
    ptr_t ptr;
    mine(ptr_t ptr) : ptr(ptr){}
};


mine m(foo_ptr);
```

When I try to compile this code I get `error: no matching function for call to 'boost::hana::overload_t<void (*)(int)>::overload_t()'`.

See for yourself on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/4NfQqJ).....

Now my question is this:

Am I allowed to copy these overload objects around (the documentation for hana does not say one way or the other), and if so why does it fail when I put it in a class as a member?

Comment: From the error, it is trying to call the default constructor.  What happens if you pass `ptr` to `mine` by reference?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm If I pass ptr to mine by const reference it works for some reason...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is arguably a bug in Boost.Hana. The constructor of [`overload_t`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp#L50-L54) is:

```
template <typename F_, typename ...G_>
constexpr explicit overload_t(F_&& f, G_&& ...g)
    : overload_t<F>::type(static_cast<F_&&>(f))
    , overload_t<G...>::type(static_cast<G_&&>(g)...)
{ }
```

Notice that these are unconstrained forwarding references. This is the common problem of having a forwarding reference constructor be a better match than the copy constructor, when you have a non-constant object. Reduced example:

```
struct X {
    X();
    template <typename F> X(F&&); 
    X(X const&) = default;
};

X x1;
X x2(x1); // does *not* call the copy constructor
```

However, if the object were `const`, then the copy constructor would be a better match. So the short fix is to just do that:

```
struct mine
{
    ptr_t ptr;
    mine(ptr_t const& ptr) : ptr(ptr){}
};
```

And now it compiles. Likewise, as Yakk suggests, move instead of copy would also work for the same reason:

```
struct mine
{
    ptr_t ptr;
    mine(ptr_t ptr) : ptr(std::move(ptr)) {}
};
```

Comment: I'd think a move ctor would also be tempting; as in `mine(ptr_t ptr) : ptr(std::move(ptr)){}`